# Send User-Defined Fonts and Images to Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Today we process Dwg files on design automation using AutoLISP script but the fonts of some projects are user-defined fonts, is there a way to send this font(s) using one custom Activity so that Autodesk forge recognizes that font and uses it in the project dwg file?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54760122/11057988

Comment: Thanks, Rahul but as I said below, unfortunately, I do not use app bundle in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can place all the custom fonts in bundle and refer the bundle in your activity. I have answered similar question here [CustomFonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54760122/2919353)

Comment: I read this topic but I don't use app bundle and these custom fonts will not always be the same, every user can send your personal set of fonts together with the project.
If I will send all the files in a zip archive, these will work?

Comment: @FernandoTiburcio- yes that should work, let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: thanks for the support, I added a new input on the activity and workitem where I send the zip file with all the fonts and images too and this worked like a charm.